# Acceder a var dentro de: img.onload = function()

Tags: callback

Quiero acceder al resultado que se desenlaza dentro de la función que genera `img.onload`, o algo que me facilite realizar la función de comprobar las medidas mediante el siguiente código:

Espero que la idea del codigo sea clara
https://jsfiddle.net/bwLvaL1g/

Comment: Hola @Rigoli te recomiendo que te des el **[tour]**, también que te pases por los siguientes enlaces: **[ask]** y, **[mcve]**

Comment: ¿Tienes código php embedido en tu JS?

Comment: hasta el momento solo estoy haciendolo con js y jquery @Lixus

Comment: ¿Y entonces qué son estos fragmentos de código? `<?=$maxPictures;?> <?=$minPicheight;?> <?=$minPicWidth;?>`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4N6D9/1/ este código lo encontré y ahí puedes sacar las medidas de la imagen al subirla al input

Comment: @Lixus actualize el codigo quitando el php https://jsfiddle.net/bwLvaL1g/3/
lo que realmente quiero es poder leer la var "sizeIsOK" desde afuera de img.onload = function() en console.log(sizeIsOK); ya intente con variables globales y varias y nada.

Answer (score 0):

En javascript las variables locales tienen visibilidad sólo dentro de la función en donde están definidas, o sea, las funciones definen los ámbitos de visibilidad de las variables en javascript.

Por lo tanto, en el código que vos presentas la cuestión sería así:

```
$('#rPictures').on('change', function () {
  var sizeIsOK = ''  // acá definís la variable
                     // el ámbito de la misma es la función callback
  var size = 25

  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if (size < 12) {
      sizeIsOK = 'menor' // la variable ya existe, por lo tanto no
                         // es necesario escribir:
                         //     var sizeIsOK = 'menor'
    } else if (size > 20) {
      sizeIsOK = 'mayor' // lo mismo acá
    }
  }
  console.log(sizeIsOK); // => 'mayor'

  // la variable sigue siendo visible porque no salimos de la función
  // para no perderla de vista la guardamos en algún lado:
  document.sizeIsOk = sizeIsOK
})

// después de correr el callback
console.log(sizeIsOK)          // => undefined
console.log(document.sizeIsOK) // => 'mayor'
```